# Error after customize user registration

Tags: theming

A error after theming the user registration.

Code i have use in template.php

```
<?php 
function ViaGo_theme() {
$items = array();

$items['user_login'] = array(
'render element' => 'form',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'viago') . '/templates',
'template' => 'user-login',
 );
$items['user_register_form'] = array(
'render element' => 'form',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'viago') . '/templates',
'template' => 'user-register-form',
);
$items['user_pass'] = array(
'render element' => 'form',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'viago') . '/templates',
'template' => 'user-pass',
);

return $items;
}
 ?>
```

and this is the code for user-register-form.tpl.php:

```
<body id="inloggen">
  <div id="login">  
   <div id="loginform">
   <h2>Registreren</h2>
   <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>       
</div>
```

[image]

And now i have a error in de theme.inc, who now a solution on my problem ?